# How to determine the range of a set of matrices under matrix multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

If I have some set of square matrices $\{B_n\}_n\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$, then is there an efficient way to determine if another matrix $A$ is within the range of these matrices under matrix multiplication? More precisely, does there exists a finite sequence $\{n_k\}_{k\in I}$ such that
$$A=\prod_{k\in I}B_{n_k}$$
From my understanding, this problem should be equivalent to knowing whether a function is computable by a set of other functions, so I do not expect a definate answer for all cases. I haven't been able to make any headway into the problem generally, only found some basic special cases such as
$$\{B_n\}_n=\{B\}=
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
implying that the range is
$$R(\{B\})=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & k \\
  0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}_{k\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$$
As soon as I'm having to deal with three or four basis matricies, however, I've found it quite difficult to determine what their combined range is.

I would at least like to know where to learn more about this sort of problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking whether $A$ is in the semigroup generated by the $B_n$.  This is called a Reachability Problem, and can be very difficult; in general it is unsolvable.  In fact, it is known to be unsolvable even for $3 \times 3$ matrices with integer entries; it is not known whether it is solvable for $2 \times 2$ matrices with integer entries.  See e.g. [this paper by Colcombet, Ouaknine, Semukhin and Worrell](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.09597.pdf).